# Unable to add the ESP layer in scapy

Tags: scapy

I would need to add ESP() layer using scapy as seen below for creating a custom ipsec packet, but whenever i tried to append/add the ESP() layer it throw a message says ESP not defined. Can anyone help me how to add/import the ESP layer in scapy .

```
q = IP(dst="192.168.0.6")/ESP(spi=5)/TCP()
q.show2()
```

Can anyone help me out here.. Appreciate for your support

Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and had no issue, also I use _python2.7_, and _scapy (2.3.2)_

Comment: Also  try to type `ls()` on a scapy console and check if `ESP` appears in the output.

Answer (score 1):

This works out of the box with Scapy's current development version. You should probably upgrade your Scapy install from the [Github repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/).

By the way, which version of Scapy are you using? Do you get any warning message when running Scapy?